# Freeing up a TCP/IP port?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, port

`netstat -tulnap`
shows me what ports are in use. How to free up a port in Linux?

Answer (score 281):

As the others have said, you'll have to kill all processes that are listening on that port.  The easiest way to do that would be to use the `fuser(1)` command.  For example, to see all of the processes listening for HTTP requests on port 80 (run as **root** or use `sudo`):

```
# fuser 80/tcp
```

If you want to kill them, then just add the `-k` option.

Comment: I found that sending a request to the port also cleans it (i am no linux expert though)

Comment: To install fuser on Debian: sudo apt-get install psmisc (http://bitflop.com/document/107)

Comment: It worked, but I had to install psmisc too on CentOs 7 (`sudo yum install psmisc`)

Comment: `kill -9 $(fuser 80/tcp 2>/dev/null)`

Answer (score 120):

To kill a specific port in Linux use the below command

```
sudo fuser -k Port_Number/tcp
```

replace `Port_Number` with your occupied port.

Comment: This actually kills the process that opened the port and not the port itself.

Answer (score 39):

In terminal type :

`netstat -anp|grep "port_number"`

It will show the port details. Go to last column.
It will be in this format . For example :- PID/java

then execute :

`kill -9 PID`

For MAC:

```
lsof -n -i :'port-number' | grep LISTEN
```

Sample Response :

```
java   4744 (PID)  test  364u  IP0 asdasdasda   0t0  TCP *:port-number (LISTEN)
```

and then execute :

```
kill -9 PID
```

Worked on Macbook

Comment: obviously this doesn't work if the PID column is empty for that port

Comment: ...and that happens if you don't have permission to see the process... try `sudo netstat` to actually see the PIDs :)

Comment: I was trying to kill a port on an amazon ec2 instance via putty cli. Forever said it had no processes running but the port(4200 for an angular app) was still open.This is the only command that worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

To check all ports:

```
netstat -lnp
```

To close an open port:

```
fuser -k port_no/tcp
```

Example:

```
fuser -k 8080/tcp
```

In both cases you can use the `sudo` command if needed.

Comment: BEWARE: fuser kills the process not the port. Which means if the port's stuck in limbo, can it work at all? This is not the right answer.

Comment: Duplicate to the first two answers.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `tcpkill` (part of the `dsniff` package) to kill the connection that's on the port you need:

```
sudo tcpkill -9 port PORT_NUMBER
```

Comment: this just hangs `$ sudo tcpkill -9 port 5432
tcpkill: listening on lxcbr0 [port 5432]`

Answer (score 11):

The `"netstat --programs"` command will give you the process information, assuming you're the `root` user. Then you will have to kill the "offending" process which may well start up again just to annoy you.

Depending on what you're actually trying to *achieve,* solutions to that problem will vary based on the processes holding those ports. For example, you may need to disable services (assuming they're unneeded) or configure them to use a different port (if you do need them but you need that port more).

Answer (score 6):

Kill the process that is listening to the port in question. I believe netstat shows you process ids.

Comment: netstat -anp|grep <port>
the last column has the process

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to kill a process immediately, you send it a KILL signal instead of a TERM signal (the latter a request to stop, the first will take effect immediately without any cleanup). It is easy to do:

```
kill -KILL <pid>
```

Be aware however that depending on the program you are stopping, its state may get badly corrupted when doing so. You normally only want to send a KILL signal when normal termination does not work. I'm wondering what the underlying problem is that you try to solve and whether killing is the right solution.

Comment: This did not resolve my issue with ssh port forwarding. [`sudo fuser -k Port_Number/tcp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750705/4575793) did.

Answer (score -2):

I think the only way will be to stop the process which has opened the port.

Answer (score -8):

sudo killall -9 "process name"

Answer (score -13):

Shutting down the computer always kills the process for me.

Comment: shutting down a server machine is rare.

Comment: did you get your "funniest" badge ?

Comment: No need for shutting down your computer.

Comment: Best idea ever 10/10

Comment: unlike some of the other answers, this will surely work

Comment: -14 votes damn that must be a world record