# "Apache started [Port 80] Busy..."-This type of error shows

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

My xampp is not working. I am getting the following error

```
Apache started [Port 80] Busy...` error is shown in xampp-control.
```

While I`m typing in browser`s url `localhost/phpmyadmin`, it shows `Not Found  HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.`

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows-7 Ultimate 64-Bit

Comment: That's not an error message but Apache's status.

Comment: Try @taz0k netstat command

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5832317/965907

Comment: Skype also use port 80 .. try to quite skype then start apache and then start skype or you use another port for apache by configure it ..

Comment: But when i`m typing localhost/phpmyadmin in google chrome browser it shows Not Found HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Comment: And when you type localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe port 80 is used by another program.
On Windows you can see if there is any other program using port 80 with the command

```
netstat -a -b
```

You can also try using a different port than port 80 and see if that works. See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15029626/2802916

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to find a port which is using:

```
netstat -an | find "80"
```

If the result like this, some programm is using 80 port

```
TCP 127.0.0.1:80    0.0.0.0:0    LISTENING
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80` to find the process which use port 80 and stop it.

Otherwise, you can change the port in httpd.conf to something else, after change, save it and restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

Start->Accessories right click on "Command prompt", in menu click "Run as Administrator" (on Windows XP you can just run it as usual), run `netstat -anb` then look through output for your program.

BTW, Skype by default tries to use ports 80 and 443 for incoming connections.

You can also run `netstat -anb >C:/ports.txt` It will print info to .txt file related to all ports and you can search easily.