# windows 8 NT Kernel and System using port 80

Tags: apache, windows-8, xampp, port80

This has long bugged me. after upgrading to Windows 8, i already cannot run my XAMPP server without using ports other than port 80, since a process called "NT Kernel & System" is using it. It's a system process so I cannot disable it. I don't have any IIS or Web Server installed so I am pretty frustrated how to use that Port 80.

If anyone of you who knows how to change the port "NT Kernel & System" uses, that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Port 80 is being used by SYSTEM (PID 4), what is that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430141/port-80-is-being-used-by-system-pid-4-what-is-that)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I ran into this problem after installing just Apache 2.2.22 on Windows 8. What I'm strongly convinced of after scouring many forums for information is that the most common cause of this issue on Windows, which produces the "make_sock could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80" error, is that IIS is running. Stopping the World Wide Web Publishing Service is what finally enabled Apache to start for me as well.

Comment: I suspect VisualStudio to have drive-by-installed this web server in my case.

Comment: In russian localization "Служба веб-публикаций"

Answer (score 37):

I ran into the same problem with NT Kernel listening on port 80 when I wanted to get my own application listening on that port.

After stopping

- IIS
- World Wide Web Publishing service
- IIS Admin Service
- SQL Server Reporting services

the NT Kernel was still listening on port 80

It was finally when I stopped the "Web Deployment Agent Service" that it stopped listening on 80.

Note: use `netstat -bano` in an elevated command prompt to see what apps are listening on which ports.

Comment: I had IIS already disabled. Now disabling "SQL Server Reporting services" solved the problem.

Comment: damn, it was: SQL Server Reporting services.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. save my day. It was actually SQL Server Reporting services

Comment: In my case was "Web Deployment Agent Service". Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

a whole bunch of services might have grabbed port 80:

http://lordamit.blogspot.de/2012/06/windows-7-windows-8-apache-errorport-80.html

it's hard to say which one caused your system to do it, i had to disable the "World Wide Web Publishing Service".

Comment: I had the same problem and disabled the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to World Wide Publishing, I had to stop the **Web Deployment Agent Service**, which kicked off the HTTP Service.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Windows Server 2016 standard. I followed the steps below;

1.Stopping the SQL Server Reporting Service(SSRS) helped free port 80.
2.configured SSRS to a different port 81. Then restart the service

Answer (score 0):

stopping the w3svc service worked for me - just write in an elevated command prompt (VS2017 command prompt started as administrator):

```
sc stop w3svc
```