# Which port can be used for apache instead of port 80

Tags: apache, xampp

Apache is not working on my PC because "NT Kernel & System" is using port 80 of my PC, I tried to stop "NT Kernel & System" from Task Manager but is dosent stop. So I am looking for another port which may solve my problem. I used port 8000, Apache can start from this port but dont work.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? Did you go to localhost:8000?

Comment: Any port that is not currently in use. 8080 is common practice. And as above, if you are using any non standard port (80, 443) then you will need to include the port number in the url

Comment: Try taking a look at the accepted answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492025/windows-8-nt-kernel-and-system-using-port-80

Comment: I opened the file "C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf"and changed two line "Listen 80" and "ServerName localhost:80" by "Listen 8000" and "ServerName localhost:8000". Then start Apache from Xampp and it show me that Apache is running, but when I go to localhost from browser I see this error massage "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."

Answer (score 1):

If your error message was:" Port 80 in use, "unable to process" with PID 4." And you are using Windows, most likely you have the NT Kernel & System, which is a system process, using port 80.  I followed the file location to xampp/apache/conf/https.conf there were 3 places in my file that used the port number which I changed from 80 to 8080 by using the Ctrl+f keyboard shortcut to find any 80 in the file.  After I saved the file, I went to my control panel and clicked config, then service and port settings and updated my 80 port to 8080. This started up my Apache server. 
The last step was adding ":8080" after localhost in my web address bar.