# Apache will not start due to Port 80 in use (all obvious solutions already went through)

Tags: apache, xampp, windows-server, ports

I was hosting 3 websites from my home server with IIS and due to all of the issues I ran into like sendmail with a php script, I completely uninstalled IIS from Server Manager and installed xampp. I am using Windows Server 2012 R2. Apache will not start due to port 80 being used. I have already tried many of the fixes scattered across the web. Things I have tried:

-Web deployment agent Service has been disabled 
-World Wide Web Publishing service is not on any list of services for my PC
-Skype is not installed on my PC
-MSSQL Server Reporting Services is disabled 
- I have ran netstat -aon | findstr :80 an serched for all prosesses with port 80, and PID 4 which is NT Kernel & System.

This is where I am stuck, I can not for the life of me find out what is using port 80. I know I can change apache's listening port to 8080 or whatever but I do not want to do that as the URL would have to show that. Is it possible I could have a virus? Are there other ways to narrow down what could be causing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492025/windows-8-nt-kernel-and-system-using-port-80  assuming you checked that out

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is point a browser at your server and see what pops up. Sometimes a shutdown and then a restart (not a restart from the Start button, but an actual shutdown) helps clear up various M$ server issues. Good luck!

Comment: Not sure I am following you? My server is not hosting anything currently, that is what I am attempting to do with xampp rather than IIS. So I am not sure what you mean when you say, "point a browser at the server."

Comment: If *something* is listening on 80, it may give you some response that may help you determine what it is.