# Windows Azure emulator 2.1 not running on express mode

Tags: azure, localhost, appfabric, azure-compute-emulator

Upgraded my windows azure project to 2.1 and i cannot get the local emulator to work any longer.

I get this error when I run on express mode
"the compute emulator is not running in express emulation mode. Please restart the emulator in correct mode."

I tried restarting but it just would not work.

I also tried using the full mode but get this one
-'cannot listen on pipe name 'net.pipe //localhost/dfService/ because another pipe endpoint is already listening on that name'
- I get a dfagent and windows azure development fabric logging agent not working on this setup as well.

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: I know it is an old ask but for the record. If you get 'cannot listen on pipe....' this means that some service is listening on your port 80 and blocking the agent. I found this question extremely helpful. Stopped a few services and the pain went away http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430141/port-80-is-being-used-by-system-pid-4-what-is-that