# PHP is not working on Windows after I completely installed it

Tags: php, iis

I am trying to setup php 5.5.12 on my Windows server 2008 R2

I found this good tutorial that walks you step by step

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUoqkPJEp4Y
```

After completing every step everything seems to be fine.

I created a file called phpinfo.php and put the following code into and placed it on c:/inetpub/wwwroot

```
<?php php_info(); ?>
```

But when I got `localhost/phpinfo.php` or `http://127.0.0.1:80/phpinfo.php` I get a 404 error. I do not know why it is not working. when I execute the following from commands from the command line it looks like it is working and I get many output with no error.

```
cd c:/php
php -i
```

In addition to the instruction, I added the following to the registry of windows

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP]
"IniFilePath"="C:\\PHP"
```

Can someone tell me what else do I need to make get php up and running on windows?

This is what is using port 80 on my server
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use localhost or 127.0.0.1 you need apache installed on your system too.

You can download [xampp](http://apachefriends.org/) or [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) they both come with PHP, MySql & Apache installed in them.

Comment: Don't forget to start the web server once it's installed. Seemingly obvious, but I've seen that question asked here before.

Comment: How to install Apache by it self? I don't need MySQL as I have MySQL enterprise installed?

Comment: @roun512, I installed it but it failed to start. I got this error. make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 I found this URL to fix it http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CouldNotBindToAddress but I don't know hot to stop the service that is currently using port 80.. How can I determine what service is using port 80 currently and stop that service? port 80 should be used by appache.  thanks

Comment: Port 80 is used by skype too. To determine the service that is using port 80 go to command prompt and type netstat -aon | findstr 80

It will tell you if there is any program that is using port 80 :)

Comment: I don't have skype on that server. maybe IIS? I see TCP 0.0.0.0:80  0.0.0.0  LISTENING 4 (please see screenshot in the post) It does not tell me what service is using it. How would I find out that an how can I prevent it from using it?

Comment: Follow this : http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/08/26/what-port-is-that-service-using.aspx

It will tell you what to do exactly :)

Comment: @Mike, If that didn't help then download this tool from microsoft http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

Comment: okay I know the owner of the service which is "System" at PID 4  But I don't know how to stop that from using it. I added another screenshot in my post above

Comment: @Mike, IIS is listening on port 80 too, check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430141/port-80-is-being-used-by-system-pid-4-what-is-that