# Easy PHP Apache Port Error Message

Tags: php, apache, easyphp

I am new to php and I would like to run a local testing server using easy php at home to work on school projects but when I try to start the easy php server, this error message pops up: **Apache port (80) is already used by another application ! Close this application and try to run again the server** It then gives me some instructions on how to close the application (by killing processes of selected ports), but when I right on the selected ports, the kill processes option is faded and not clickable. Maybe there something else I need to check or do on my computer to run this local host? Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark but maybe try to close Skype, if you have that running, and then start the server? If I remember correctly Skype listens on port 80 by default. If that's indeed the issue then you can configure Skype not to listen on port 80 in its settings...

Comment: My skype is currently not running or open. Thanks though

Comment: Well does it say which process is taking up the port?

Comment: It just says 4 and 4 for the top repeating local port (80) process ids

Comment: Could be IIS, like @sscotti said. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430141/port-80-is-being-used-by-system-pid-4-what-is-that

Answer (score 0):

That might be related to Skype or the IIS server using port 80.  You can configure Skype to use different ports in the preferences.  You might try going to "localhost" in your browser and see what comes up as well.  If it shows a Microsoft IIS server page then you know that the server is running.  Disabling that or turning that off depends upon your operating system.  You can probably just look that up on the internet if that is the issue.