# Port 80 is blocked by 'System'

Tags: apache, xampp, port80

I'm trying to run a portable Xampp webserver to work on a website, but I noticed that on my main computer (other computers haven't had this issue, but I can't use them much and I want to fix this problem instead of avoiding it so it's gone next time) Apache won't run, so I did a portcheck and port 80 is used by 'system'. I included a screenshot, as you can see everything else is free but port 80 is being used.

[image]

So, does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this? Finding a way to open port 80 or how to change Apache http to another port are both options, but I don't know enough about apache to trust myself not to completely screw it up and I don't know how to clear port 80.

There are a few similar questions I've found, links [here](https://superuser.com/questions/352017/pid4-using-port-80), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/43307/why-is-system-process-listening-on-port-80) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430141/port-80-is-being-used-by-system-pid-4-what-is-that) but none of them give me the answers I need.

Comment: Well, all those questions and answers you link basically cover all the conceivable possibilities. Have you really tried any of the suggestions?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález the problem is they don't work or are different and I can't figure them out on Win10, or I've magaed to screw up massively and one does but I've tried them all that I can.

Comment: Alright, accepted answer in first question starts with `netstat -nao | find ":80"`. You run that and it doesn't work? The command doesn't exist in your computer? The PC explodes?

Comment: I returns that it's listening. I then did some research and it's PID 4 using it, which suggests it's an IIS service I want to stop, which doesn't stop when I tried "iisreset /stop", nor can I seem to get apache to change the port for it's http.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález and I've looked in the active processes and theres no process using PID 4 apparently, which makes everything more confusing

Comment: See what I meant? You already gathered extraordinarily useful information following the information in those questions (port 80 is already in use and you even have the PID to look up in Task Manager). Yet you decided that such information wasn't working and you're still reluctant to say what you got so far...

Answer (score 1):

Your system might have IIS service. which uses 80 port. you need to stop that service. try following command in cmd as administrator:

```
iisreset /stop
```

Comment: I tried it, doesn't seem to work. I also tried 'NET stop HTTP'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using skype.. u should check its connections settings and remove the port 80 from it.

Comment: I'd already made sure skype wasn't the problem, and it's used by 'System', not skype

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I had to stop "Windows Sync Share" service on windows server 2012. Then I could use the port 80 and use Apache Tomcat 8.