# Apache does not start on port 80

Tags: apache, xampp, port80

First, I wanted to see what was using port 80:

```
C:\Users\[my user]>netstat -aon | findstr :80
TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
TCP    192.168.1.46:57822     72.21.91.29:80         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
C:\Users\[my user]>
```

See what I had in PID 0 and 4:

[image]

I did not have an application using port 80 from what I see. I would think that port 80 is free for an application such as Apache to use it. In the following screen, I click "Start Apache" and nothing happens. That was how I always used to start Apache.

[image]

I am trying to start Apache on port 80:

[image]

If I use a different port such as 81, 82, 83, etc., it works. But I want to use port 80 because I do not want to use http://localhost:81/ in the URL to test my site. I simply want to use http://localhost/.

Do you have an idea about why I am not being able to start the Apache service on port 80 even though apparently port 80 is free? Or maybe it is not free because this PID 4 is using it? The name of that process is `System`.

Comment: Have you a version of IIS running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Port 80 is being used by SYSTEM (PID 4), what is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430141/port-80-is-being-used-by-system-pid-4-what-is-that)

Comment: Try running "NET stop HTTP" from cmd.exe

Comment: @MartinParkin I recently installed Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and if I suspect that things stopped to work correctly for me for Apache after I installed this SQL Server.

Comment: Check for the `World Wide Web Publishing Service` running in your services.  I would speculate that this is using port 80 and preventing you from doing so.  Its service name is `W3SVC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a different port instead of 80. Not a big deal, I would have preferred to use port 80 but I can cope with not using it. That is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following;

1. Right click on **My Computer**.
2. Select **Manage**.
3. Double click **Services and Applications**.
4. Then double click **Services**.
5. Right click on "**World Wide Web Publishing Service**".
6. Select **Stop**.

Comment: This solution was listed in the duplicate link I posted.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see where you posted a link to a duplicate providing the solution I posted, am I missing something?

Comment: I do not see the `World Wide Web Publishing Service` service running.

Comment: Did you run "NET stop HTTP"?

Comment: Or look at the duplicate link?

Comment: I had a permissions issue when trying `NET stop HTTP`. I will use a port different than 80 because now I do not see the port number in the URL. See my answer to my own question.