# How Do I Start A Service Disabled in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, server

After running a `netstat` command and discovering that a system service was listening at port 80, I checked through the Internet and found this solution:

[Port 80 is being used by SYSTEM (PID 4), what is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430141/port-80-is-being-used-by-system-pid-4-what-is-that)

I ran

```
sc stop w3svc
```

then

```
sc config w3svc start= disabled
```

but the `sc config w3svc start= disabled` command returned this error

> Set-Content : A position parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'start='.

Basically, it is an invalid argument but almost every solution I have seen on this platform is suggesting this exact command line for stopping and disabling the service.

Can anyone help because I don't want to disable the whole HTTP service from the registry, I wouldn't mind being guided on how to probably bind this service to another port because I need another application that needs to use this port 80.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell has it's own cmdlet's for managing Windows Services so it's better to use those than calling a commandline tool from PowerShell. Using the commandlets gives you much better error handling.

```
Set-Service -Name w3svc -StartupType Disabled
```

See [Set-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service?view=powershell-6).

If you want to change the port that IIS is listening to from port 80 to something else you can do this via IIS Manager or with PowerShell (requires `Import-Module WebAdministration`). Here is an example to change the port for the Default Web Site from port 80 to 8080:

```
Set-WebBinding -Name 'Default Web Site' -BindingInformation "*:80:" -PropertyName Port -Value 8080
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I did ran the command and it executed, but i did a netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:80  and noticed that it is still being listening to thesame PID 4 (which happen to be label system on the services list).

I checked the file location and was redirected to ntkrnl, meaning the port is being used by both the kernel and system. 

Is there a way I can bind the ntkrnl.exe to another port without ruining the OS or something. I have an access control app that uses port 80 by the default and the technical support guy from want me to reinstall the whole OS just because of it.

Comment: You need to identify what is listening on this port, might be a website other than Default Website or even a process different than IIS. Maybe this helps: https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2012/01/02/system-process-pid-4-is-listening-on-port-80/

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell, `sc` is an alias to `Set-Content`, and aliases have a higher precedence than paths. You have two options:

1. Use cmd instead of Powershell to execute the command
2. Use `sc.exe` instead of `sc`: Your command would become `sc.exe config w3svc start= disabled`