# Kubernetes ingress returning 404 on windows

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I use the Docker desktop and enable kubernetes on windows 10. but after running the program and applying yaml files, I only get 404.I did install Ingress but I dont know what is the problem!. below is my code:

**Ingress**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: minimal-ingress
 annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
 ingressClassName: nginx
 rules:
 - host: ticketing.dev
   http:
     paths:
      - path: /api/users/?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
           name: auth-srv
           port:
             number: 3000
```

**my service:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
     app: auth
  template:
   metadata:
    labels:
     app: auth
   spec:
    containers:
     - name: auth
       image: me/auth
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: auth-srv
spec: 
 selector:
  app: auth
 ports:
  - name: auth
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finding the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63412274/404-page-not-found-when-kubernetes-ingress-nginx-is-run-on-docker-windows) but shortly it is because nginx is listening on port 80 by default and on windows probably some programs are running on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your deployment and add container port reference just like below and reapply:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
     app: auth
  template:
   metadata:
    labels:
     app: auth
   spec:
    containers:
     - name: auth
       image: me/auth
       ports:
         - containerPort: 3000
           name: auth
```