# The process with PID 4 could not be terminated from my default user Administrator

Tags: apache, iis, cmd, pid, administration

I need to turn off my other listening port to run the apache server.
My os is Windows Server 2019. There has running IIS. I tried to terminate it through cmd but showing the following error.

> ERROR: The process with PID 4 could not be terminated.
> Reason: Access Denied.

How to turn off my running listening port to run my apache server?
I can't open cmd through a foreign address. I have tried several methods even tried also VirtualBox on windows 7 but didn't work.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask].

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/352017/pid4-using-port-80 and [Port 80 is being used by SYSTEM (PID 4), what is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430141/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Port 80 is being used by SYSTEM (PID 4), what is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430141/port-80-is-being-used-by-system-pid-4-what-is-that)