# "Apache shutdown unexpectedly" even after reinstallation

Tags: xampp

[image]

Here is my netstat. When I click start the mysql it only says attempting to start my sql service and nothing happens and with Apache it shows an error message.

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
9:30:47 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
9:30:47 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
9:30:47 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
9:30:47 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
9:30:47 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
9:30:47 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: still the same i already did some solution but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the Netstat-Application System uses Port 80 for something. You have to find the program, which uses this Port and stop it. Then it should work.

Comment: but it says use by the system

Comment: You could try stopping the program with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26653919/16633193