# Wamp - no operation is available

Tags: wamp

I just installed wamp.
I started the application and 2 things:

1. I keep getting red light.
2. when I press the icon nothing happens, I am pretty sure it should have come up with a menu or something.
   I can't restart or nothing...

I am administrator, I tried reinstalling.

ideas?

Thanks

Comment: see my complete solution,about it in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158432/wamp-port-80-busy

Answer (score 0):

Is there any other program using port 80 ? so that apache can't start ?
tried already to start the services by hand?
Start Menu - Run - Services.msc 
and look for apache and mysql.
What OS are you running? make sure you haven't IIS running.

Comment: just to shrapen the problam I can't even right \ left click it with the mouse, nothing happes...

Comment: sorry, for the separated comments: I also tried starting the processes by hand, didn't work also.

Comment: Ah, win7. Did you install WAMP as Admin !? disable uac.

Comment: yes, I have tried disabling uac, didn't work. I have ti say that I had this program before and I uinstalled it threw revo and not it's not working. BTW can I use xampp the same way?