# Installing WAMP

Tags: wamp

I am trying to install WAMP from wampservice.com
The download and installation go smoothly, but when I try opening http://localhost/, the screen appears totally blank.

Why do you think is that?

Thank you in advance!
I am an absolute newbie to Drupal and using http://localhost/.

Comment: Have you started the various services via the taskbar?

Comment: Taskbar of WampServer you mean?
Yes, I have. Still blank localhost page.

Comment: see my complete solution,about it in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158432/wamp-port-80-busy

Comment: see my complete solution,about it in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158432/wamp-port-80-busy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if IIS is running, check services.msc for the "World Wide Publishing Service", disable and try again.

Also make sure you are not running SKYPE (there is an option to change the skype port).

Close all additional running program to minimise chance of conflict.

Failing that you should test your port 80 from wamp menu > Apache > Service and let us know the results.

Comment: SKYPE was the answer!
Thank you so much! :)
Now, you are saying I can go to SKYPE options and change the port?
To which one?

Comment: I just re-ran my SKYPE having WAMP on, and they both seem to be working.

Comment: Skype is funny - it tries to take over port 80 if it's not already being used, so running WAMP and then Skype won't cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use WAMP, it's a great tool.  Click on the gauge icon in the taskbar, and select "Start All Services" - see if that works.

Comment: Thank you!
I just did, and tried restarting all services also - didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on your `/wamp/www/` directory..

I had a similar issue when I installed WAMP to `C:\Program Files\` instead of `C:\`

Answer (score 0):

An other solution could be to simple alter the appache httpd.conf.
You can acces this file from the wamp menu > Apache > httpd.conf

Next alter the

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

To for example

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:7080
Listen 7080
```

Restart wamp and services
then type http://localhost:7080 and you'll have wamp up and running

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

1. Downloaded the wampserver (32 or 64 bit): http://www.wampserver.com/en/; than installed it.
2. In the **Skype**: goto **Tools > Options… > Advanced > Connection** and uncheck the checkbox which says “Use Port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections”
3. Push the ***Win+R*** for a run-console and write: "**inetmgr**"; hit **Enter**; 
   [ *this is the Internet Information Service Manager    (IIS-Manager)*]
4. Under Sites you can see Default Web Site, **right click** on it and Select EDIT BINDINGS.
5. Edit HTTP binding port from 80 to 81.
6. Open your browser and type: //localhost:81/yoursite. 
       You should be able to access your local sites without any problems
7. I let in my httpd.conf the port setting as it was:
   **"#Listen 12.34.56.78:80

    Listen 80"**
8. I went to my favourite browser and just typed: **localhost**
   ;) **Wow!**

The following link did help me to:
http://www.gadgetcage.com/how-to-change-iis-port-in-windows-7/3457/