# what after changing port in xamp

Tags: wamp

using webmatrix (IIS ) and xamp (apache) since `IIS` is listening port **80** , i configure apache file `httpd.conf` and changed each port to *11* in place of *80* .Now my xamp showing green icon . but now when i tried to access some file of /www/example.php i got

```
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
```

with url http://localhost/example.php

Comment: see my complete solution,about it in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158432/wamp-port-80-busy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since this question was asked by me so i am answering it in formal way. i'm answering because like me no other guy conflict .
ANSWER : i have change the url scene i have changed the port . so

```
http://localhost:<port>
```

so finally url becomes `http://localhost:11/example.php`