# Busy... Apache started [Port 80]

Tags: apache, xampp, port

I use XAMPP 1.7.7 after start Apache I get this alert:

> Busy...
> Apache started [Port 80]

And I have opened the `httpd.conf` file and I have changed the port number to `8080` or `85`.
But I still have above alert after reset XAMPP and start apache.

What should I do?

Comment: see my complete solution,about it in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158432/wamp-port-80-busy

Answer (score 6):

It is because teamviewer or skype is using this port by defalut in you system.
So the port 80 is busy , either you can try by changing the port number of skype/teamvier

Or go with the following Solution

Goto - >C:\xampp\apache\conf

open File - httpd.conf

Make changes as below

Listen 8080

ServerName localhost:8080

C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra

open->httpd-ssl.conf

Make changes as below

Listen 4499

ServerName localhost:4499

Restart apache now :)

http://localhost:8080

Comment: It was not working until I changed "httpd-ssl.conf". @Chaitanya, Can you please explain?

Comment: what problem are u facing?

Answer (score 4):

I have checked the source code for XAMPP control panel. It is not really 100% hardcoded. It looks for a *dynamic* value, if not found, it says port 80. Well, the *dynamic* value **DOES NOT** come from your httpd.conf file

To change the port in `Apache started [Port 80]` message, do as follows:

1. Find location of xampp-control.exe. It should be in the root of your installation directory.
2. Create a file "XAMPP.INI" in that directory (so that XAMPP.ini and xampp-control.exe are in same directory)
3. Put following in the XAMPP.INI file:

> [PORTS]
>   apache = 8080

Now , you will always get `Apache started [Port 8080]`. Use whatever port you want to display in XAMPP.ini file. Please note that, this is for display purpose only. It has no relation with your httpd.conf

Comment: In my installation the filename is `xampp-control.ini`

Answer (score 3):

XAMPP 1.7.4 and XAMPP 1.7.7 display misleading port information in the XAMPP Control Panel.

Regardless of which port you specify Apache to listen to, the XAMPP Control Panel will always display:

> Apache started [Port 80]

This is WRONG!!!! This is a HARDCODED string in XAMPP 1.7.4 and 1.7.7. It does not reflect the actual port Apache is listening to.

see more here: http://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-the-apache-port-in-xampp

Answer (score 1):

I found Skype took over port 80 after I installed it and interfered with my Web server.  There is a setting in Skype you can change so that it uses another port by default and leaves 80 open for the Web server.

Answer (score 0):

The Xamp Control Panel is Bugged. Most of the time the httpd.exe is already started but the Green Indicator is not showing.. try to open your browser and open the site...

But then check your xampp configuration also,,

Comment: is this an solution to problem? i dont think so

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  How did I solve it? The Port 80 seems to be used by other programs.  In my case XAMPP stopped working when I installed Microsoft WebMatrix.  The Apache stopped working.  When I uninstalled WebMatrix with all its components, Apache started working great.  I hope this can help anyone who had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. The Port 80 seems to be used by other programs. In my case,too XAMPP stopped working when I installed Microsoft WebMatrix. The Apache stopped working. When I uninstalled WebMatrix with all its components, Apache started working great. I hope this can help anyone who had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. It was completely solved by following these two instructions:

> 1. Launch RegEdit:
> 2. Go to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP
> 3. Add a new DWORD (32-bit) value
> 4. Name it ‘NoRun’ not including the quotes
> 5. Double click the new property
> 6. In the Value data field type ’1′ not including quotes and click OK
> 7. Re-boot your computer

The above works for some people, but not for me, in addition I had to follow this too:

> 1. Go to regedit.exe go at:
> 2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SYSTEM>CurrentControlSet>services>HTTP
>      and change,the reg_dword named “Start” ,it’s value to zero (“0″ without quotes) ,press okay.
> 3. Then restart.
> 4. **THE IMPORTANT IS to open your server as fast your computer starts so port 80 is taken by apache…

I found this solution on this site, which explains further: http://www.cameroncooke.com/2009/01/25/windows-7-uses-port-80-and-makes-it-impossible-to-install-apache-solution/comment-page-3/#comment-1099

Answer (score 0):

Solved it for me. I updated XAMPP to PHP 5.4 and afterwards i could not start the Apache anymore. It said Start Apache (Busy). The problem was for me the Pando Media Booster (Apperently it comes with League of Legends :) ) which was blocking the port 443. So after uninstalling it, it worked again. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yeh, i have faced the same problem, what has append in my case is i have installed SQL Server  and "SQL Server Reporting Services" is running in port 80 so that is the issue.

when i stopped that service, i could be able to run Apache on port 80

Answer (score 0):

http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/opening-up-port-80-for-apache-to-use-on-windows

Windows 8 Skype can't be changed from using port 80; so it's a few choices ... Race for what get's it first ....
Uninstall what uses port 80 ....
Best answer : Free-up your server and its resources, Install only min needed software or apps, use a second computer to edit your server, and do your other things like Skype if you want real performance

These issues or run a rounds, should only be happening on Virtual Machine setups, which of coarse can still be avoided except for the performance loss well never be regained 100% and often the image is only licensed for 3 month periods anyways.

Windows 10 well have multi desktops .... it well probably be best to allow some users to install their own apps like Skype and not have their choices/installs effect other users or vice versa depending on who all makes the choices or is primary user(s). On a multi user system, the headache might be someone not around enough, who might just not be able to keep accepting new requests being that so many programs want the port.

Answer (score 0):

Search for control panel
Chose uninstall programs
Chose "Turn Windows features on or off" located on left side of panel
Under "Internet Information Services" deselect "World Wide Web Services" that Microsoft must turn on by default (takes port)
Reboot and WAMP came back up as before.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this procedure** : [How to change XAMPP apache server port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port/21914920#21914920)

It explains how resolve apache port issues in 4 steps :

1. Choose a free number port
2. Edit the file "http.conf"
3. Edit the file "http-ssl.conf"
4. Configure XAMPP Apache server settings

**If you still got a problem after try this process** : this means that an application uses all available ports or dynamically change.

> For exemple Skype port is dynamic, it can change the port if it is
>   already occupied.

Simpler solution is to exit Skype, and then start Apache, then start Skype again. This is one time operation and solves the problem