# Wamp server "The connection to the server timed out" error

Tags: wamp

I'm using WAMP in my localhost, I put it online, now I did ipconfig in my cmd, my ipv4 address looks like 192.xxx.x.xx,

when I access that address in my PC's browser, it loads my localhost (which is expected), but when I load that ip address in my android tablet device, I'm getting an error:

```
"The connection to the server timed out"
```

Anyone knows a fix? Thanks a lot!

Comment: see my complete solution,about it in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158432/wamp-port-80-busy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure your pad and your PC is in the same lan?

Comment: No, but I expect this can work, because I tried it before, I have a localhost set up at home and I can access it here at the office...

Comment: as i know, any ip like 192.* is a lan ip. so you may be using a wan ip that time.

Comment: i used this site http://www.mywanip.com/ to get it but i'm getting the same error...

Comment: where are you now, home of office?

Comment: are you using "localhost" or ip to access?

Comment: ok, well, so you're using your wan ip addr of your office pc to access your site on your tablet, right?

Comment: so i think that's the problem, try to restart your Apache and reload your page with lan ip.

Comment: nice, so it should be the reason that your apache didn't bind the lan ip addr at first, and the wan ip of your office pc is your company's router's ip.

Answer (score 0):

If your Android device and PC are on the same LAN then it is possible that a firewall on your PC is blocking access. Check that Apache (and port 80) are allowed in the firewall configuration.

Comment: If you are using the Windows firewall check under `Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall` 

But I notice above you say that both devices are not on the same LAN, if this is the case then you will not be able to access it. `192.*.*.*` is an internal IP and will only be accessible to devices on the same LAN. You would have to use your WAN/Public IP (as assigned by your ISP) to make this server accessible to devices that are not connected to the same LAN as your PC.

Comment: apache http server is checked on that... however i used this site mywanip.com to get my wan ip but i'm getting the same error...

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities for this Problem

1. Server (your pc) and Client(another pc) are not belongs to same network
2. Firewall Blocked Connection, Check the OS firewall and also Antivirus if any
3. The both client and server belongs to same network as public, there is 
   possibilities to Block, change that private mode and check