# assigning a port used by xampp to wamp

Tags: xampp, localhost, port, wamp

I installed WAMP software on my PC for web development.
When I try to access `localhost` I get a message telling me that it's being used by XAMPP.
I know that I can change the port used by WAMP to some other port number by making changes to `httpd.config`.

But is there any way that I can stop XAMPP from using port 80, and let it be used by WAMP?

Keep in mind that XAMP is is not currently installed, someone had previously installed it and then removed it.

Comment: see my complete solution,about it in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158432/wamp-port-80-busy

Answer (score 0):

Check [stop system process using port 80](http://teocomi.com/stop-system-process-using-port-80-how-to/) for solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change [xampp server port](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/07/how-to-change-xampp-server-port/).