# Running Wordpress on port other than 80

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I have apache running on port 1024 and WAMP Server is running fine.  But when I try to run Wordpress at localhost:1024 the install wont work.

I have tried everything I can think of but I cannot get it running.  Anyone had this problem?

Thanks Daniel.

Comment: First, this is better suited at superuser. No programming here. Second, without any information about what is (not) happening: No chance of getting help here!

Comment: see my complete solution,about it in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158432/wamp-port-80-busy

Comment: I Restart WAMP then works.

Answer (score 1):

You must edit the file wp-config.php and change the following:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost:1024/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost:1024/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress will natively run on any port apache runs on (I use various ports for test servers daily)

Make an index.php with something like

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And test if you can display the page. If the page doesn't display then your apache settings are misconfigured. (Check /etc/apache2/sites-available/default)