# App using Port 80

Tags: windows-xp, port

How can we able to check whether any application, which uses **Port 80** in **Windows XP** ?

Comment: Using what programming language? From the command line, `netstat -b` should work.

Comment: see my complete solution,about it in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158432/wamp-port-80-busy

Answer (score 1):

Use `netstat -aon` and look for the address ending in :80 and note the corresponding PID in the same row. Then go to task manager (CTRL-ALT-DEL), click Processes tab and under View click Select Columns then check PID (Process Identifier). The PID in Processes that matches PID from netstat -aon is listening on your port.

Skype, which is a very common app running in the background, is a common cause of port 80 being occupied.