# testmysql.php WAMP setup

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am trying to install WAMP on my computer. I opened phpinfo just fine, but when I try to run testmysql.php, I get a very blank page. Any echo statements before mysql_connect work fine, but any echo statements afterwards never show up.

testmysql.php:

```
<?php 
echo 'before';
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
echo 'after';
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connection OK'; 
mysql_close($link); 
?>
```

the log fine mysql.log has

```
130503 14:39:26 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130503 14:39:26 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130503 14:39:26 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130503 14:39:26 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130503 14:39:26 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130503 14:39:26 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130503 14:39:26 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130503 14:39:26  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130503 14:39:27 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
130503 14:39:27 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
130503 14:39:27 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
130503 14:39:27 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130503 14:39:27 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130503 14:39:27 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130503 14:39:27 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

so i believe the problem lies in setting mysql on an actual ip address. how do i do this?

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158432/wamp-port-80-busy/16251034#16251034

Answer (score -1):

Check your php.ini and set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` (`error_reporting  =  E_ALL`).
I think you get a fatal error and the script stops after that!

Comment: i set error_reporting to E_ALL like you said, but again, nothing shows up! i dont know what it could be

Comment: the only error i am getting is `127.0.0.1 - - [05/May/2013:15:18:43 -0400] "GET /testmysql.php HTTP/1.1" 500 6` which is not helpful. it is in the file `access.log`

Comment: Open cmd with admin privilèges and type `php -i > C:\phpConfig.txt` and post the content of the file here. The file will be in `C:\phpConfig.txt`