# Check Port 80 for sites

Tags: port

I need to check if port 80 is up for the accessing IP.

I have tried

$checkport = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errnum, $errstr, 2); //The 2 is the time of ping in secs

This is giving a result. But recently I have found that port 80 is up for access from normal connection is also returning as Port 80 up.

Reason I found was : ISP had enabled port80 for those accessing my site.

Can anyone help me out in this regards.

Thanks in advance.

Adarsh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16251034/1339004

Comment: I need to check if the port of the visitor accessing my site have port 80 UP. Please help me.

Comment: You can find what software is using port 80 by two different way. check this link: http://openguider.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/how-to-solve-port-80-problems-on-windows/