# Getting wampserver working?

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I have tried going to Apache, open `httpd.conf` and change the lines #Listen 12.34.56.78:80; Listen 80 to #Listen 12.34.56.78:80; 8080 and still it did not work. I have went to control panel and `System & Security-> Administrative Tools-> Services`, then Web Development Service (It did not exist). I also tried `start->run->cmd` and pressing ctrl + shift + enter, to open command window. I typed `net stop MsDepSvc` and it did not work either. I know it is there some where because I keep getting the error that `HTTPAPI/2.0` is running. What else can I try?

I am getting an error when I try to turn off `Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0` In order for me to get wampserver on, I have disable the `HTTPAPI/2.0` but my computer for some reason does not show the `Web Development Service Agent`. So What do I do?

**None of the comments listed below helped. It cannot find certain files either.**

Comment: Maybe http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Check for the logs..`C:\wamp\logs`

Comment: you have reporting services installed on microsoft sql server?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Microsoft SQL Server` installed with `SQL Server Reporting Services` try to stop or disable this service from `Control Panel->System and Security->Administrative Tool->Services->SQL Server Reporting Services (InstanceName)`. More details how to find this service [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158432/wamp-port-80-busy/24090026#24090026).
Other cause to block 80 port is Skype.

And if you want to change the apache port to 8080 you need to do this:
Find in `httpd.conf` the lines :

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

and replace wtith:

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:8080
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080
```

and after restart Wamp server.

You replace only the commented line. The line start with `#` is comment in `httpd.conf`. The next line after this is what to replace like in my example.

Comment: @Abdulwahid yes