# GET request to IIS returns Microsoft-HttpApi/2.0

Tags: iis

I've got 6 identical machines running IIS and Apache. Today one of them decided to just stop serving requests. I can access all of the webapps when I try from localhost/resource but when I try from url/resource I get a 404. I did a Get request against the machine that isn't working and I get this back:

- Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
- Connection: close

Compared to a working server:

- Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
- X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
- Content-Type: text/html

Tried searching for this problem but came up with nothing, anyone got any idea's?

Comment: Did you check host header configuration on IIS?

Comment: Kinda off topic here, but check your services to see if one has started that shouldn't be. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158432/wamp-port-80-busy

Comment: In my case the issue was that I've created IIS bindings to a specific IP address instead of "`*`". After binding to "`*`", everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 19):

Windows has an HTTP service that manages calls to IIS and other HTTP enabled services on a windows machine. Either you need to configure it to handle your calls, or, in the case of WAMP or similar non-IIS-web-server-on-windows scenarios you may just need to turn it off.

When you see **"Microsoft-HttpApi/2.0"** returning error, such as 400 "bad URL" or "bad header", etc. the problem is most likely because *the HTTP.sys service is intercepting your http request and terminating it because it does not meet with the minimum validation rules* that are configured.

This configuration is found in the registry at **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters**. In my case, it was choking because I had a RESTful call that had a 400 character segment in the url which was 160 characters more than the default value of 260, so I

1. added the registry parameter **UrlSegmentMaxLength** with a DWORD value of 512,
2. stopped the service using **net stop http**
3. started the service using **net start http**

I've run into these issues before and it is easy to troubleshoot but there is very little on the web that addresses it.

Try these links

- "[the underlying problem is that the client has sent a request to IIS that breaks one or more rules that HTTP.sys is enforcing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2009/01/29/how-to-troubleshoot-http-400-errors/)"
- [enabling logging on HTTP.sys is described here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/820729/error-logging-in-http-apis)
- [a list of the HTTP.sys parameters that you can control in the registry is found here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/820129/http.sys-registry-settings-for-windows).

Comment: Great references!

Comment: I also had to run 'net start w3svc' in cmd to get my site back on line.

Comment: I tried these steps on window server 2016 IIS 10, but not working still getting "Microsoft-HttpApi/2.0" in response

Comment: for me, the server was out of disk space

Answer (score 10):

A bit late, so put here for posterity ;-)

After trying all sorts of solutions found on the web, I almost gave up, but found this little nugget.

If the response's Server header returns `Microsoft-HttpApi/2.0`, it means that the HTTP.sys is being called, not IIS.

As a result, a lot of the workarounds will not work (URLScan, etc).

This worked however:

1. Open regedit
2. Navigate HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\
3. If DisableServerHeader doesn't exist, create it (DWORD 32bit) and give it a value of 2. If it does exist, and the value isn't 2, set it to 2.
4. Finally, restart the service by calling `net stop http` then `net start http`

src: [WS/WCF: Remove Server Header](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2017/12/18/wswcf-remove-server-header/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2017/12/18/wswcf-remove-server-header/)

> Set below registry flag to: 2
>   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\DisableServerHeader
>
> Setting this to 2 will ensure that self host WCF services no longer sends the SERVER header and thus ensure we are security compliant.
>   Please note that this disables ALL server headers.
>
> The default value of 0 enables the header, and the value of 1 disables server header from DRIVER (http.sys), but app can still have headers.

For me I had to restart the server for the changes to take effect.

Hope this helps someone

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you! This is the only way I think it works for a 400 bad request. Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: No probs, glad to be of some help to someone :-)

Comment: It works ..Superb!!!!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, running Windows 10 Pro, it was the Windows MultiPoint Service.

By executing:

```
net stop wms
```

Port 80 was released.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on our web app on a client's site and ran into an issue where the site root pages loaded, but the reports folder always returned a 404 for files that existed in the folder. The 404 page showed the .Net version of 2 when the application was set to 4, and a test of a non-existent page in the root returned a 404 page showing .Net 4.

I tried just http://localhost/reports and got back a Microsoft Reporting Services page. Not part of my application.

Be sure to check just the default document of the folder when a unexpected 404 comes up and the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

This question and series of replies helped me get to the bottom of the related issue I was having. My issue centered around using just a subdomain to go to our server (e.g. typing "www/somepath" into the browser while on our corporate network), which had worked in the past on an older server, but no longer worked when the system was upgraded to a new server. I saw the unexpected `Microsoft-HttpApi/2.0` string in the header when using the Chrome Devtools to inspect the Network traffic.

My HTTP.sys process was already logging, so I could verify that my traffic was going to that service and returning 404 NotFound status codes.

My resolution was to add a binding to the IIS site for the subdomain, making IIS respond instead of the HTTP.sys process, as described in this server fault article - https://serverfault.com/questions/479274/why-is-microsoft-httpapi-returning-404-to-my-network-switch