# WAMP - won't start

Tags: binding, port, wamp

I followed all the instructions re: seeing what is using port 80 available at [How do I free my port 80 on localhost Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788348/how-do-i-free-my-port-80-on-localhost-windows) but I have no idea what to do about it... so far there is a Sony-VAIO process, my virus app and chrome (my browser)...

How do I change things so WAMP server can be used on my Windows 7 computer?
I'm a noob on both ports, binding and web servers.

Many thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16251034/1339004

Answer (score 2):

One thing to looks for is skype it tends to hog port 80. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a port that is already being used by another
 program you could see busy ports by going to command prompt and typing

```
netstat -ao
```

Also you should allow access to that port in your default browser too. You can find out how to do this for Firefox 3 by reading this article: [Unblock a nonstandard port in Firefox3](http://bdbits.wordpress.com/2008/07/01/unblock-a-nonstandard-port-in-firefox3/).