# Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80 Node on azure server (Windows server 2012 r2)

Tags: node.js, windows, azure

I stopped the World Wide Web Publishing Service and changed the Startup Type to Disabled and ran as administrator to start the website but received the EACCES.

Is this a permissions error? I have read that running the website with sudo on linux / unix fixes this, but what about on windows?

EDIT: I ended up using iisnode as I could not resolve the EACCES error on port 80. Here are the steps I used to get my node server running on iis through iisnode module:

*Install iisnode (wherever you want);
*Install 'URL Rewrite' plugin for iss;
*Create new site;
*Create web.config file with:

1. handler mapping for iisnode on server file with path to server file;
2. rewrite url rule that any request to url goes to server file;
3. debugging and logging (with path to log file destination) set to true;

(Please find an example web.config file at the bottom of this post)

*Give SERVER/IIS_IUSRS write permissions to the directory / virtual directory found in iis of the site;
*Create local binding;
*Create external binding with *:80 as port;
*Make sure that node's http listener is set to listen on process.env.PORT as iisnode will set this environment variable to 80 for http requests;

Example web.config file in the root folder and assuming that the node server (in this case it will be called app.js) is also just in the root folder too.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
             <!--Tells iis that app.js is to be handled by iisnode module-->
    <handlers>
        <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" /> 
    </handlers>
        <!--Url rewrite rule that anything coming to any url of within site goes through app.js-->
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="toNode">
                <match url="/*"/>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

EDIT: For the most part, I followed this tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUYCDnqR8p0

Comment: Should I just try the iisnode module?

Comment: try to run on some other port,

Comment: but i still need it to run on port 80

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run `node` app on port `80`, then you have to run it with `sudo` privileged account.

For windows, probably, restarting iis node can resolve the issue.

[run node.js webbapp on 80 port on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030371/run-node-js-webbapp-on-80-port-on-windows)

Comment: It is a windows server

Answer (score 0):

I want to reproduce the issue via create an Azure VM using the image `Windows Server 2012 R2 DataCenter` from gallery, but failed that the node app works on port 80.

Per my experience, there are some steps you can try to resolve the issue.

1. Select the `Command Prompt` and right click to select the option `Run as administrator` to startup the `cmd` for running node or others as administrator.
2. Command `netstat -ao` to display the all listening ports and their PID, then find the one of Local Address `0.0.0.0:80` and command `taskkill /PID <PID> /F` to forcefully terminate the process ran on port 80.
3. Try to command `node app.js` again.

Comment: Tried exactly that already. I ended up just using iisnode and configuring that. If anyone would like to know the necessary steps to get iisnode running, I can share.

Comment: @pbordeaux Thanks for your sharing. That's helpful for everyone that got the same issue. Please describe the details include the OS, middleware, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate a Node.js Azure Webapp from Azure CLI.

1. Install Azure CLI with NPM:

   `c:\> npm install azure-cli -g`
2. Login to your azure account:

   `c:\> azure login`
3. Change mode to *asm*

   `c:\> azure config mode asm`
4. From your local git repository, create an azure webapp (named *yoursite*):

   `c:\git\yoursite> azure site create --git yoursite`

This will generate add all the necessary settings in the `issnode.yml` file.

5. Commit with git:

   `c:\git\yoursite> git add . && git commit -m "initial commit"`
6. Push the modifications to the azure server:

   `c:\git\yoursite> git push https://yourlogin@yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/yoursite.git`

Azure will add the node dependencies and run your site on port 80.