# Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:444 node.js while listening on port 444/443

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I am developing webrtc application using node.js.When I run the command 'node server.js' getting following error.

```
running on https://localhost:444
    events.js:160
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:444
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1246:19)
    at listen (net.js:1295:10)`enter code here`
    at Server.listen (net.js:1391:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Websites\WebRTC\server.js:16:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

And my server.js is

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    express = require('express'),
    https = require('https'),
    http = require('http');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

http.createServer(app).listen(444);

console.log('running on https://localhost:444');
```

Thanks.

Comment: it's windows 10

Comment: it's probably a permissions issue in windows as well - try running the command prompt as an admin account

Comment: I tried the same but still the same error.Also host my solution on windows server 2012 R2 IIS-8 but no change!.

Comment: nothing wrong with your code - tried it, it works fine

Comment: try `netstat -anb` to see if anything is listening on port 444 already

Comment: 444 port is free.

Comment: on localhost it works fine but on server(windows server 2012 R2 IIS-8) showing above error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030371/run-node-js-webbapp-on-80-port-on-windows

Answer (score 8):

Listening on port below 1024 requires root access
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only

Just run the app by prepending command with sudo

```
sudo node server.js
```

Comment: windows is not linux, and windows has no sudo

Comment: Author didn't mention that before I posted my answer. Sorry for that.

Comment: Indeed. But the error message includes a windows style path