# Apache in xampp is not starting

Tags: php, xampp

With out Skype also it showing below error. But .NET is is installed. Please give solution.

```
 16:02:53  [Apache]     Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
 16:02:53  [Apache]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing ependencies, 
 16:02:53  [Apache]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
 16:02:53  [Apache]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
 16:02:53  [Apache]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
 16:02:53  [Apache]     If you need more help, copy and post this
 16:02:53  [Apache]     entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: "Press the Logs button to view error logs and check"

Comment: It’s quite possible that some other service is using Port 80. If you have SQL Server Express, for example, or some other process using Port 80, then you will have to find it and stop it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788348/how-do-i-free-my-port-80-on-localhost-windows or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows. Alternatively, you might try to run XAMPP on some other port.

Comment: As far as I can see, this is not really a PHP question. I suggest you add the tags `windows` and `apache`, as they are likely to be more related to the problem.